# Identify Miyata bike from ca 1990

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm just saving and restoring a Miyata bike from ca 1990. I think the model was called Sport Cross but I cannot find it in any old catalogues. I find the model but the info doesn't quite match up. For example I can find a Sport Cross from 1991 but that one is with 700c wheels and mine is for 559 wheels.

It's a butted steel frame and all I know is that the fork is CroMo. The stickers on the frame is too worn out too see.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I doubt that;s the original handlebar - looks way too wide for the period.

Comment: Koga Miyata, or any bike with Miyata tubing?

Comment: I think the only thing original is the frame...

Comment: It's just a miyata

Comment: Looking again the rear brakes look like V brakes but there's a center mount which would have been for cantilevers.   Nothing wrong with that upgrade, but 
rear brakes are certainly not original.  I suspect the front hanger was lost/removed when the bars were changed.

Comment: Absolutely. I think the only thing that's original is the frame + fork.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found out that it's a Miyata SportRunner.

Comment: That’s cool, good to have an answer - I reckon you can accept it as correct if you’re satisfied. It would be interesting to know how you found out the answer